# python's request post not sending

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I've been trying to do a post an image file toward a deep dream website via python code, but every time I try, I'm getting returned to the main homepage. I am still new to the request's post method, but after a few hours of search, I do not seem to know what's wrong.

here's the code that I have tried:

```
import requests


url = 'http://psychic-vr-lab.com/deepdream/'
files = {'imagefile': open('test.jpg', 'rb')}
print("sending file to "+url)
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(r.text)
```

And here is the payload when I try it in my browser

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryVe3sVw1pN61EAIZ3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imagefile"; filename="test.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryVe3sVw1pN61EAIZ3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"

5000000
------WebKitFormBoundaryVe3sVw1pN61EAIZ3--
```

any help on understanding will be great!

Comment: 1. `URL` should be http://psychic-vr-lab.com/deepdream/upload.php. 2. You should specify a full path to file instead of just its name

Comment: I tried that earlier, and it does send a error message saying "File type needs to be jpg." eventhought it IS a jpg. And I doubt giving full path will fix as giving a invalid, say tests.jpg throws an exception.